# How to "get rid of" $(SolutionDir) when building Visual Studio project from outside Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild

I want to build a .vcxproj via MSBuild from outside Visual Studio. The problem is that there are many occurrences of $(SolutionDir) inside the .vcxproj file which apparently only get set correctly when the solution is loaded.

When I replace $(SolutionDir) with the actual absolute path, it works. But other people on other machines are working with the same project file, so this is not a solution.

Is there a solution or hack to solve this problem?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can set the variable by passing parameter arguments:

```
/p:SolutionDir=path
```

So, rather than editing the solution file, you can create a build script that sets up the environment and executes MSBuild accordingly, leaving the Visual Studio file as is for development work.

Comment: It was a good answer in 2013, but NuGet later switched to `nuget restore` command https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-restore so such tricks should no longer be used.

Answer (score 9):

You can use a relative path.

I am not sure about Visual Studio 2010 as in the question, but it guaranteed works since Visual Studio 2012.

If the project folder is right under the solution folder then the relative path is `..\\`.

This, by the way, can be combined with the parameter argument from [Grant Thomas's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15053915/how-to-get-rid-of-solutiondir-when-building-visual-studio-project-from-outs/15053967#15053967).

```
<SolutionDir Condition="$(SolutionDir) == '' Or $(SolutionDir) == '*Undefined*'">..\</SolutionDir>
```

Comment: Traversing up directories doesn't work in TFS checkin builds when overriding .targets for example. Need absolute paths.

Comment: Please state this should go in the `<PropertyGroup>` element of the relevant `*.csproj` file.  I feel this is an important piece of information missing from your answer.

Answer (score 8):

The solution to explicitly pass `SolutionDir` as an argument is insufficient for me.

Namely, if the project I want to build has dependencies with different build configurations, the build fails with a `This project doesn't contain the Configuration and Platform combination of <my target configuration>` error.

This makes sense, since I didn't specify the target configuration for the dependencies and thus it tries to target same configuration as the project I'm building, which they don't have (in my case).

Since a solution file contains the build configurations for all projects in the solution (given some solution-configuration), we want to make use of this solution to solve this problem. Luckily, MSBuild allows us to build a solution and pass a specific target project as argument, which will only cause that project to be build (together with its dependencies).

```
msbuild MySolution.sln /t:MyProject
```