# MSBuild builds solution but fails to build the project

Tags: f#, msbuild, visual-studio-code

I have F# project which I want to build with command line (to use that later in FAKE config).
The problem is that MSBuild fails to resolve assembly dependencies when I use it on the project file directly. While it goes fine when I use solution file with this single project included.

I really have run out of ideas. The solution file seems to not contain any critical information.

Another weird thing is that VSCode also fails to resolve one of those assemblies. I hope that when I fix MSBuild config I may be will able to see what's wrong with VSCode.

Command line:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\msbuild.exe" FSharpWeb1\FSharpWeb1.fsproj /t:rebuild
```

Error message:

```
C:\work\MNP\testMSBuild1\FSharpWebApi\FSharpWeb1\FSharpWeb1.fsproj(173,5): error MSB4062: The "MSBuild.ExtensionPack.FileSystem.File" task could not be loaded from the assembly C:\work\MNP\testMSBuild1\FSharpWebApi\FSharpWeb1\*Undefined*\packages\MSBuild.Extension.Pack.1.3.0\tools\net40\MSBuild.ExtensionPack.dll. Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\work\MNP\testMSBuild1\FSharpWebApi\FSharpWeb1\*Undefined*\packages\MSBuild.Extension.Pack.1.3.0\tools\net40\MSBuild.ExtensionPack.dll' or one of its dependencies. The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect. Confirm that the <UsingTask> declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.Done Building Project "C:\work\MNP\testMSBuild1\FSharpWebApi\FSharpWeb1\FSharpWeb1.fsproj" (rebuild target(s)) -- FAILED.
```

I've pushed the minimal demo to github: https://github.com/alehro/testMSBuild.git

It's actually easy to reproduce independently. In VS 2015 Community edition create new project  from F# Web Template named "Web Api 2.2" and then try to build it with MSBuild.

Another disturbing thing is that the minimal demo produces different errors from those I've seen yesterday. Also vscode complains on different items. If yesterday it could not resolve a couple of calls, now it complains on all of:

```
open System.Net.Http
open System.Web
open System.Web.Http
open System.Web.Routing
```

telling that neither of them is defined.

Comment: Steps to reproduce? Error message?

Comment: What dependencies does the project have and which of them are failing to get resolved? Are they NuGet packages with solution-level package restore?

Comment: @MarkSeemann I've added details

Comment: @HonzaBrestan Please see details I've added. The project has standard dependencies Asp.Net Web.Api projects have. Not sure about "solution-level package restore." I've googled and found a couple on nasty topics. It looks that my .fsproj file is compatible with nuget 2.7 and above. So, I have no idea how it could affect my situation.

Comment: Thanks, the new details show a lot more about the problem! First thing I can notice is that in your .fsproj there's a `<UsingTask>` MSBuild reference to `MSBuild.Extensions.Pack` with a path containing `$(SolutionDir)` property. This is the `*Undefined*` in the path in your error. This property is set automatically when building the solution in VS, but has to be passed to MSBuild as seen here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15053967/1659828

Comment: It also means that when you run MSBuild on this project file, you already need to have this .dll ready in the packages folder, which, outside of VS, you'll have to do manually via `nuget` CLI

Comment: But since you mention FAKE in your question, it may just be easier to start writing the FAKE script right away and use its [RestorePackages](http://fsharp.github.io/FAKE/apidocs/fake-restorepackagehelper.html) Target

Comment: This actually seems even better for the SolutionDir path: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33782131/1659828. And sorry for spamming comments, but I haven't really tried most of it so I'm not sure it warrants an answer.

Comment: @HonzaBrestan Passing SolutionDir with command line does the job. Please publish your comment as answer. Yesteday's project has many such cases and it helped there also. This is strange why MSBuild didn't warn about missing variable.

Comment: @HonzaBrestan vscode errors also disappeared when I added the variable to .fsproj file

Comment: Published, glad it worked!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reformatting my comments to a response now that it's verified it works:

Your `FSharpWeb1.fsproj` references `MSBuild.ExtensionPack.FileSystem.File` task from `MSBuild.Extension.Pack`, but the path specified in the `<UsingTask>` tag contains `$(SolutionDir)` property which is not defined when you run MSBuild outside of Visual Studio.

The error message you're getting shows that in the highlighted part of the path:

> The "MSBuild.ExtensionPack.FileSystem.File" task could not be loaded from the assembly C:\work\MNP\testMSBuild1\FSharpWebApi\FSharpWeb1\***Undefined***\packages\MSBuild.Extension.Pack.1.3.0\tools\net40\MSBuild.ExtensionPack.dll.

This can be remedied by conditionally setting the relative path when the property is not set by VS:

```
<SolutionDir Condition="$(SolutionDir) == '' Or $(SolutionDir) == '*Undefined*'">..\</SolutionDir>
```

(original response for this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33782131/1659828)

One more thing I mentioned in the comments is that this solution assumes you already have the necessary dependencies downloaded in the `packages` folder. Visual Studio does that automatically by restoring NuGet packages before build, but when you build in another context, *you* have to make sure the packages are restored, otherwise the build will keep failing.

Comment: It works, thank you. Though that is strange that MSBuild doesn't complain about missing variable. I haven't expected such carelessness.